# didReceiveIncomingCall is called although it is a missed call

Tags: ios, voip, sinch

When the app is in background and an incoming call has happened and the user didn't pick up. When the user gets back into the app `- (void)client:(id<SINCallClient>)client didReceiveIncomingCall:(id<SINCall>)call` is being invoked.

Steps to reproduce

- User A caller
- User B receiver
- User B has the app in background
- User B calls user A
- User B hangs up the call before user A picks up
- User B opens the app and `- (void)client:(id<SINCallClient>)client didReceiveIncomingCall:(id<SINCall>)call` gets immediately called and the `call.status` is 0 so `SINCallStateInitiating`

Is this the normal behaviour? Is there a way to know this call is not "available" anymore?

I am working with iOS 10 and Sinch version: 3.9.7-26289c8

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Showing the code on how I initialize Sinch client, Manged Push, Notifications, etc. All the below code takes place inside the AppDelegate

**AppDelegate**

`@interface AppDelegate ()<SINCallClientDelegate,SINManagedPushDelegate,SINClientDelegate>`

**Initializing SINManagedPush**:

AppDelegate in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
self.push = [Sinch managedPushWithAPSEnvironment:SINAPSEnvironmentAutomatic];
self.push.delegate = self;
[self.push setDesiredPushTypeAutomatically];
```

**Initializing Sinch Client**: once the user is logged in

```
- (void)initSinchClientWithUserId:(NSString *)userId {

    if (!_client) {
        _client = [Sinch clientWithApplicationKey:[BCEnvironment sinchAppKey]
                                applicationSecret:[BCEnvironment sinchAppSecret]
                                  environmentHost:[BCEnvironment sinchEnvHost]
                                           userId:userId];

        BCUser *user = [BCDataProvider loggedInUser];
        [self.push setDisplayName:[user displayName]];

        _client.delegate = self;
        _client.callClient.delegate = self;
        [_client setSupportCalling:YES];
        [_client enableManagedPushNotifications];
        [_client start];
    }
}
```

**Registering for remote notifications**

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    [self.push application:application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}
```

**Receiving push notification**

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    [self.push application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo];
}
```

**SINManagedPushDelegate**

```
- (void)managedPush:(id<SINManagedPush>)unused didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:(NSDictionary *)payload forType:(NSString *)pushType {
    [self.client relayRemotePushNotification:payload];
}
```

**SINCallClientDelegate** -> This is called no matter if the call doesn't "exist" anymore

```
- (void)client:(id<SINCallClient>)client didReceiveIncomingCall:(id<SINCall>)call {
    //This opens the calling screen, even if the call is "old" and the caller has already hangup or the call timed out, etc. Here is where I am having the issue
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DidReceiveCall" object:nil userInfo:@{@"call":call}];
}
```

Comment: I am facing same Issue. while opening app after missed call , it redirect me to calling screen as i am getting call state initiating.

Answer (score 0):

Are you relaying the push data to the client your self? If so you can check the payload in the result

https://download.sinch.com/docs/iOS/latest/reference/html/Protocols/SINNotificationResult.html#//api/name/isValid

Example use:

```
id result = [self.client relayLocalNotification:notification];
if ([result isCall] && [[result callResult] isTimedOut]) { 
    NSString remoteUserId = [[result callResult] remoteUserId]; // present       
    UIAlert indicating user has a missed call. } 
else if([result isMessage]){ 
    NSString messageId = [[result messageResult] messageId]; // show view controller that highlights the particular message 
}
```

Comment: thank you for answering. Inside `managedPush:didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload` I am capturing the result from `relayRemotePushNotification` When the device is in background and gets a call, I receive a `SINNotificationResult` with everything ok. So the `[result isValid]` is true and `[[result callResult] isTimedOut]` is false. Which makes sense because the call is ongoing correctly, the user is just not picking up. After the calling user hangs up, the called device opens the app and the `client:didReceiveIncomingCall:`. At this point I don't have any info about the status of the call

Comment: Hi, so is this a race condition, where you hangup while you are trying to connect?

Comment: I wouldn't say it is a race condition, since `client:didReceiveIncomingCall:` gets called even if the call was hangup by the caller already some time ago.

Comment: Any ideas on what I could try? Or any additional information I can give? Thanks!

Comment: Anychance to share the code where you configure the client with all the push etc?

Comment: Hi @cjensen, I have added the code I am using to initialize the client, managed push and handle the notification. Please let me know if there is any other information I can provide. Thanks!

Comment: Any news regarding this? Was the additional info I provided useful? Thanks!