# Sinch - Delegate Method not called firs time while app is force closed

Tags: ios, voip, sinch

I have integrated SINCH in one of my app.currently i am facing below issue

> "If A User's App is completely
>   terminated state and another one calling him. he will not get any Push
>   for the First Time,But the Push is coming for the Second Attempt."

I have implemented **Pushkit with SINManagePush.** **didReceiveIncomingPushPayload** is called but method for **didReceiveIncomingCall** or **didReceiveLocalnotification** not called.

I have checked that my SinchClient is not nil , [SinchClient isStarted] & Sinch delegate is not nil.

While going through Sinch' Doc for iOS , i have found below comments

> Normally, when an iOS app enters background mode, all its sockets are
>   closed by the OS. Since iOS 8, VoIP push notifications provides a
>   transport channel for signaling incoming calls even if an application
>   is in the background. For iOS 6 and iOS 7, or if remote push
>   notifications is not desired, iOS also provides a way for a VoIP app
>   to keep a socket connection alive even when the application moves into
>   the background.

As **setSupportActiveConnectionInBackground** is deprecated , for ios 8 and above how can i start socket while receiving voip push while app is terminated?

**Update 14-02-2017**

> A local notification representing an incoming call is removed if the
>   call times out.

=> while notification is removed from notification removed from tray , callDidEnd is not called.So that while opening app , didReceiveIncomingCall delegate is called and it redirect to incoming call screen.**Is there any Solution to avoid this situation?**

I have read [this question too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40423173/didreceiveincomingcall-is-called-although-it-is-a-missed-call) , it does not help me.

Comment: Voiop push should be delivered all the time, apple is depreciating the socets in ios 10 so its not a good idea. The didRecieve incoming call, is it called when you open the app or never?

Comment: No , if call is expired then this method is not called

Comment: @cjensen - And also , as i am using PushKit , now  i am receiving call (VoIP notification) every time , but i am getting header nil every time.is there any method so that i can retrieve headers from callId?

Comment: @cjensen - And now i am facing above issue fro particular one device(iPhone 6+ , iOS 10.2.1) only.I have checked that all other device received call regularly.

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati any updates?

Comment: @Alexander , Nope!